# iOS: Notifications sent from server using JavaPNS not arriving

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am attempting to send push notifications using JavaPNS. I have done this in the past without a problem, but for this particular app, I can't get it to work.

When I send a notification from my local machine, they show up on the device correctly. When I send it from a Windows Server, JavaPNS reports that the notification was sent successfully, but it never shows up on the device. I have checked that ports 2195-2196 are open.

Here's the really weird part: When I put my application that sends the notifications onto a different server, one which is currently successfully sending push notifications to a published app, the notifications still do not arrive. So it can't be a server setting.

There must be something internal to my JavaPNS application that's sending correctly from my local machine but not from the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a similar issue was posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/issues/detail?id=177).

For whatever reason, it appears to be Java 1.7 that is causing the problem. I rolled my install of Java on the server back to 1.6, and the notifications arrive successfully. Hopefully this will help point others in the right direction if they run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

JavaPNS javapns-jdk16 
Java1.6 compatible